# Handling Category Collisions

Tags: amcharts

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h7zf55b0/

I have a graph I am trying to design with the given data.  The problem is I am getting category collision as its possible that multiple data points have the same date (which I use as the category axis).

```
{
'data': "18.46",
'date': "2015-12-31T09:36:00.0000000Z",
'type': "bid"
},
{
'data': "40.3918",
'date': "2015-12-31T09:36:00.0000000Z",
'type': "ask"
},
```

amcharts is handling this by drawing the columns over each other as shown in the fiddle.

Is there a way to make amcharts put these columns next to each other?  Or stack them?

Ideally I want to be able to specify 'type' as a grouped element or something, so that the columns are labeled "40.3918 ASK 9:36am"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On date-based category axis, the chart tries to retain natural time scale. So if you have several columns on the same category, it draws them over each other.

You can disable this functionality by setting [`equalSpacing: true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#equalSpacing) in your `categoryAxis`.

This way the chart rather than putting columns where they are supposed to be in time, will put each data point consecutively, regardless of the order and distance in time between them.

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "gridPosition": "start",
  "parseDates": true,
  "equalSpacing": true,
  "minPeriod": '60ss',
  "axisAlpha": 0,
  "gridAlpha": 0,
  "position": "left"
}
```

As for what is shown in the balloons, you can use [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonText) or, if you need some very custom functionality to generate balloon data [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction).

---

Another option would be to combine those data points into same-category data points, as well as define a graph for each type:

https://jsfiddle.net/h7zf55b0/1/

Comment: equalSpacing does the job correctly, the second option won't work because I won't know all the different values of "type" to make multiple graphs...  But that second option actually looks right, I'd prefer to have each different "type" a different color.. hmm

Comment: You could modify the code to create a graph for each distinctive "type" automatically.